# In Vim :CocInstall coc-flutter not working

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I use Ubuntu 18.04

1. This writes when opening .vimrc.

> $ vim .vimrc
>
> [coc.nvim] "/path/to/node" is not executable, checkout https://nodejs.org/en/download/

2. There are these in .vimrc.

```
syntax on
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
set number
filetype off                  " required
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'dart-lang/dart-vim-plugin'
Plugin 'natebosch/vim-lsc'
Plugin 'natebosch/vim-lsc-dart'
Plugin 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
let g:lsc_auto_map = v:true
let g:coc_node_path = '/path/to/node'
```

3. I make .vimrc PluginInstall.
4. Vim version 8.2.

5.:CocInstall coc-flutter does not work.

What can I do? Flutter doesn't write automatically.

Comment: Dart sdk flutter was also installed. Installed on the system, it was fixed.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and close the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"------- dart flutter ------------

```
if count(g:bundle_groups, 'dart')

    Plugin 'natebosch/vim-lsc'
    Plugin 'natebosch/vim-lsc-dart'
    Plugin 'dart-lang/dart-vim-plugin'
    Plugin 'thosakwe/vim-flutter'

endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Dart sdk flutter was also installed. Installed on the system, it was fixed.